# material-ui makeStyles: how to style by tag name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I want to add a rule for all `<p>` in the current component. I couldn't find information anywhere (material-ui documentation, Stack Overflow, etc.) on how to add CSS rules by tag name.

Is it not supported?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        'p': {
            margin: 0,
        },
        someClass: {
            fontSize: 14,
        },
    })
);
```

**EDIT:**

Using Ryan's solution works, but creates a new problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            '& p': {
                margin: 0,
            },
        },
        // I want this rule to override the rule above. It's not possible in the current configuration, because `.root p` is more specific than `.title`
        // This problem originates from the fact that I had to nest the rule for `<p>` inside a CSS class
        title: {
            margin: '0 0 16px',
        },
    })
);

export default () => {
    const classes = useStyles({});

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <p className={classes.title}>My title</p>
            <p>A paragraph</p>
            <p>Another paragraph</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: You can add a css file to your project and import it like `import 'style.css'`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you want this scoped to your component, you need a class to apply to your component (e.g. `classes.root` in the example below). Then you can target all `p` elements within that using `& p`. If you then need to override the `p` tag styling for another CSS class within your component, you can use another nested rule to target `p` tags that also have that class (e.g. `classes.title` in the example).

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& p": {
      margin: 0,
      "&$title": {
        margin: "0 0 16px"
      }
    }
  },
  title: {}
}));
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>This paragraph isn't affected.</p>
      <p>This paragraph isn't affected.</p>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <p className={classes.title}>My title</p>
        <p>A paragraph</p>
        <p>Another paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Target nested tags in JSS]

Related documentation: https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.1.1#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule

Comment: That works, thanks! Unfortunately now I have a new issue: the rule of `.someClass p` is too specific, meaning it overrides the other styles in this `createStyles` object

Comment: @LiranH Please show those other styles in the code in your question.