# Material-UI styles and html / markdown

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, javascript-marked

Our application is build using Material-UI library (with themes). As part of this app we are parsing markdown to html ([marked library](https://github.com/markedjs/marked)).

How can you apply material-ui themes ( Typography ) to a pure html ?

Somehow

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: marked(markdown code)}}/>
```

Should have the styles as defined by material-ui Typography

Comment: Is there any reason you chose `marked` over a react specific library that has easier support for this?

Comment: @JacobSmit , no reason.  But I don't want a library that adds a lot of react nodes as content is 'static'.

Comment: Fair enough. As a piece of interest then, one of the co-founders of Material UI answered a question about markdown and typography before and linked to an example of how they are (or at least were) handling the markdown for the documentation website. https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12290#issuecomment-453930042

Comment: @JacobSmit , that helps . thanks.  Looks as it's a 'manual' work

Answer (score 16):

The styles for all the `Typography` variants are in the theme at `theme.typography.<variant>` (you can browse those entries in the default theme here: https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#default-theme). You can leverage this to create styles to target the tags you want to support as shown in the example below:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  const tags = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"];
  const nestedRules = {};
  tags.forEach((tag) => {
    nestedRules[`& ${tag}`] = { ...theme.typography[tag] };
  });
  return {
    root: nestedRules
  };
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Typography
      className={classes.root}
      variant="body1"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html:
          "<h1>H1</h1><h2>H2</h2><h3>H3</h3><h4>H4</h4><h5>H5</h5><h6>H6</h6><p>default body1</p>"
      }}
    ></Typography>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit style html tags]

Related answer: [material-ui makeStyles: how to style by tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345362/material-ui-makestyles-how-to-style-by-tag-name/61346003#61346003)

Answer (score 6):

use regular `Typography` component and pass that HTML in a similar way as it is passed in the question.

```
<Typography
    variant="h2"
    color="primary"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<p>Hi from inner HTML</p>" }}>
    
</Typography>
```

One catch is here that when `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is passed then don't pass anything as children.

Here is a working demo :

[image: Edit nervous-cookies-nedrz]

*Note: Also make sure that the function `marked(markdown code)` returns the HTML in string.*

Comment: This might works with a single tag, but doesn't work with multiple ones  (h1,h2.. ) ->   https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-wildflower-p6dvq  .. check how the styles are generated.

Comment: I guess it is working as the color and font family of h2 variant is getting applied. Of what part you think this is not working?

Comment: is it bcoz of fontSize?

Comment: You expect the html inside h1 to use variant h1, the html inside h3 to use variante h3.. it's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`markdown-to-jsx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx) npm package. [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/blog/Markdown.js) is the example from the material ui templates.

You basically have to create a config object that ReactMarkdown likes, that is specific for material ui

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';

const styles = (theme) => ({
  listItem: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
});

const options = {
  overrides: {
    h1: {
      component: Typography,
      props: {
        gutterBottom: true,
        variant: 'h5',
      },
    },
    h2: { component: Typography, props: { gutterBottom: true, variant: 'h6' } },
    h3: { component: Typography, props: { gutterBottom: true, variant: 'subtitle1' } },
    h4: {
      component: Typography,
      props: { gutterBottom: true, variant: 'caption', paragraph: true },
    },
    p: { component: Typography, props: { paragraph: true } },
    a: { component: Link },
    li: {
      component: withStyles(styles)(({ classes, ...props }) => (
        <li className={classes.listItem}>
          <Typography component="span" {...props} />
        </li>
      )),
    },
  },
};

export default function Markdown(props) {
  return <ReactMarkdown options={options} {...props} />;
}
```

I got that straight from their example.

Comment: Bundling a whole MD parser just to style a couple of tags...

Comment: @IvanKleshnin it's 5.7kb gzipped.